# Qt5, Ubuntu. Failure in building an app with Opengl

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, opengl, qt5

I'm a novice in Qt5, want to make a simple programm with interactive 3D graphics. I create a new Qt Widgets app, following manuals I do `QT += opengl` in .pro, `#include<QtOpenGL>` in .h, and that's all. I even don't add any extra code, I click "build project" and get this:

> /opt/qtsdk/5.5/gcc/include/QtGui/qopenglext.h:117: ошибка: typedef
>   'PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC' is initialized (use decltype instead)
>   typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC) (GLenum mode,
>   GLuint start, GLuint end, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const void
>   *indices);   'GLenum' was not declared in this scope    'GLuint' was not declared in this scope    'GLsizei' was not declared in this scope
>   'GLenum' was not declared in this scope    expected primary-expression
>   before 'const' typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC)
>   (GLenum mode, GLuint start, GLuint end, GLsizei count, GLenum type,
>   const void *indices);    typedef 'PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC' is initialized
>   (use decltype instead) typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC)
>   (GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalformat, GLsizei width,
>   GLsizei height, GLsizei depth, GLint border, GLenum format, GLenum
>   type, const void *pixels);

and same on and on till I stop building as I get the 8140th error, which isn't the last. :\
Please, help!! Tried everything, can't take it anymore
I installed Qt5 (lib and IDE together) by online-installation, then tried to fix them:

```
$ apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev    
$ sudo aptitude install mesa-common-dev      
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libfontconfig1
```

etc. Tried everything, that managed to find regarding my problem (though google says nothig useful solving exactly my problem)
OS: Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 32bit

Video card: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (Total crap. Maybe, that's an issue?)

OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 (Does QtOpengl use a default Оpengl, preinstalled on my laptop, or uses its own Opengl? Though, how do versions of Opengl and Qt correlate? Would Qt4-5 even work witn an old Opengl version?)

Qt version: 4.8.6 (At least console says so, but I'm not shure that projects aren't built with Qt5 libs. How can I explicitly specify the version I need to build the project by the way?)

Auto-detected Qt version: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 32bit

QMake version: 2.01a

Auto-detected compiler: GCC; debugger: GDB

Need your help very much! Thanks

The only code I have:
That's mainscene.h:

```
#ifndef MAINSCENE_H
#define MAINSCENE_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include<QtOpenGL>
#include<QGLWidget>

class MainScene : public QMainWindow
{
       protected:
          void initializeGL();
          void resizeGL(int w, int h);
          void paintGL();

       public:
          Scene3D(QWidget* parent = 0);
};

#endif // MAINSCENE_H
```

That's the  SimpleOpengl.pro:

```
QT += core gui
QT += opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = SimpleOpengl
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
        mainscene.cpp
HEADERS  += mainscene.h
```

That's the main.cpp:

```
#include "mainscene.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainScene w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

(It's all wrong, isn't it?..)

Comment: Did you install Qt4 before ? Anyway, the fact that you use the Qt5 Kit should build the program using Qt5. Did you try a QMake and re-build all ? Sometimes QMaking it makes the trick. Also, can you post your Widget's code (the includes and the place where you use the OpenGL code)

Comment: No, I didn't, I started right with Qt5. Qmake works fine, but re-build gives the same result I complained about.
Added code into my first message.

Comment: Look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116254/how-do-i-change-which-version-of-qt-is-used-for-qmake You can possibly have other Qt in the system even though you did not explicitly install it. If you use Qt Creator that should not be the case though: check Project settings.

Comment: Are you just missing `libglu1-mesa-dev`?